# Are there infinitely many pairs of rational numbers such that...

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Are there infinitely many pairs of rational numbers $(a,b)$ such that $a^3+1$ is not a square in $\mathbf{Q}$, $b^3+2$ is not a square in  $\mathbf{Q}$ and $b^3+2 = x^2(a^3+1)$ for some $x$ in $\mathbf{Q}$?

This question can be phrased also as follows:

Are there infinitely many rational numbers $(a,b)$ such that the extensions $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{a^3+1})$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{b^3+2})$ are quadratic and equal?

Comment: What motivated this question?  It seems like this should have some relation to elliptic curves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  Consider the two elliptic curves:
$$7r^2 = a^3+1$$
and
$$7s^2 = b^3+2.$$

One can check (using SAGE or MAGMA) that these two curves have infinitely many rational points (in fact they both have rank 1).

For rational points $(a,r)$ and $(b,s)$ on these curves we have that $a$ and $b$ satisfy the requirements of your question.

Comment: I chose 7 because this was the smallest square-free positive integer for which both curves have positive rank.  If you don't care that $a$ and $b$ vary, you could take $b=0$ and look at the curve $2r^2=a^3+1$, which has infinitely many rational points.

Comment: Question: Do I understand correctly that we always have $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{a^3+1}) =\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{7}) = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{b^3+2})$ if $(a,r)$ and $(b,s)$ lie on the curve?

Comment: I like this answer a lot. It prompts the following question: Are there infinitely many square-free integers $n$ such that $nr^2=a^3+1$ has positive rank and $ns^2=b^3+2$ has positive rank?